# Protected React route redirects before props receive Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

When I refresh the page, my protected route made with `react-router-dom` is rendered before `mapStateToProps` fires and the component receives props. This causes redirection to `/login` route, although I'm already logged in.

I have a Redux store looking like this:

```
const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {}
};
```

and a component named App.js which contains routes:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.token)
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);

    store.dispatch(loadUser());
}
```

Where `setAuthToken` method is adding headers to axios requests.
There's also `loadUser()` method which is an action creator with such code:

```
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {
    if (localStorage.token) {
        setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
    }

    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/user');

        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOADED,
            payload: res.data
        });
    }

    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

So it basically changes a store's `isAuthenticated` field to true and adds user's info into the `user` object in the store, if there is a JWT token in the localStorage.

In my protected route component I have code that redirects to `/login`, if Redux store has `isAuthenticated` equal to false.

```
render() {
    if (this.props.auth.isAuthenticated === false)
        return (<Redirect to={'/sign-in'}/>);
```

Now, everything works fine if I click a link to a protected route from the navbar. If I'm logged in, then the protected route shows. If I'm not, then I'm redirected to the `/login`.

The problem occurs when I refresh the page being on the protected route. I'm immediately redirected to `/login`, because the page is rendered before the component receives Redux store's state in props.

How can I fix this? Should I somehow wait for the props, or rather change the method of routes protecting?

Comment: You need a third state (unknown) for your `isAuthenticated` property (depending on your taste, `undefined` might be appropriate), and to act on it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Well one easy way to fix this would be to add a loading state to your reducer. Add a simple action that is dispatched at the beginning of loadUser that turns loading to true and after the API call when your reducer hits the USER_LOADED case it turns loading to false, fills the user state, changes isAuthenticated to true/false depending if the user is logged in. And change the condition on your protected route component to this.props.auth.isAuthenticated === false && !this.props.user.loading.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't precise I was using Redux Thunk in my project. That's why I got those errors with premature rendering. I solved my problem by saving all the necessary info in my JWT Token. Thank you for your help